# ctypes convert Python boolean array to C++ boolean array to pass into function

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a C++ function that takes in the argument `(const BOOL channels[])` and this is the variable that is passed when calling it in C#:

```
bool[] achannel = new bool[16];
achannel[0] = true;
```

I'm wondering how I could convert this to Python using ctypes in order to call the function successfully from a Python application.

I've tried  this:

```
achannels = [None] * 16
achannels[0] = True
```

But end up with this error:

```
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000039
```

Comment: `bool[] achannel = new bool[16];` isn't legal C++ - do you mean `bool* achannel = new bool[16];`?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Sorry, I didn't realize that was actually from *C#* code that was making a call to the library which is written in C++. I updated the question to reflect this. Anyways, your answer worked -- thank you!

Comment: Python , C#, and C++ all at once? Now all you need is some Fortran. Quite the melting pot project your got there :) cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function parameter of type `const BOOL channels[]` is a *pointer* to a `const BOOL`. The argument you want to pass is a pointer to a bool, which happens to be the first element of an array of 16 bools. I'll assume that whatever `BOOL` is in your C++ code is compatible with C99's `_Bool` and therefore `c_types.bool`.

You can construct your desired argument as

```
arr_type = ctypes.c_bool * 16
achannels = arr_type(True, *[False]*15)
```